# Staphylococcus AG structure?

Tags: microbiology, proteins

I found this statement in my study materials in the section of Staphylococcus

> The AG structure:
>
> - protein AG (species specific);
> - polysaccharide AG (serotype specific).

I know what is Protein A/G, a recombinant fusion protein that combines IgG binding domains of both Protein A and Protein G.

**What is the point of this AG structure thing in the contex of Staphylococcus?**
Can we say that staphylococcus have AG structure? 
I think it has properties related to protein A\G and also to polysaccharide A\G.
I know very little about polysaccharide A\G and not sure how it is related to serotype specificity in the context of staphylococcus.

**Extension to the question**

```
Antigenic structure of Steptococcus pyogenes: 
the group AG is unique, placing streptococcus in group A.
```

**What is the AG here?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After puzzling over this for a while I think I have the answer . It's nothing to do with protein A or protein G. I think that whoever wrote your study materials meant Ag which is a common abbreviation for 'antigen'. I guess this was in the context of immune responses, or strain typing.

Looking back over your last few questions, it seems that you are at the mercy of a teacher who specialises in ambiguity.

Comment: I added one more confusing statement which I do not understand about S.pyogenes. Do you understand AG there?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lancefield_grouping

"a method of grouping beta haemolytic bacteria based on the carbohydrate composition of bacterial antigens found on their cell walls."